# Defining italic small caps globally using fontspec in LuaLaTeX

Tags: fonts, fontspec

I am using an OTF font that has small caps but not italic or slanted small caps, and there are a smattering of places throughout a large document I'm working on where italic small caps are needed. I know I can do it on a one-by-one basis with a `\newcommand` but I was hoping to avoid needing to go back through the whole document and find all the cases where it's not compiling correctly and just define the fake italic small caps as the shape for the whole document. I tried the following, but it didn't produce the effect:

```
\setmainfont{Sabon LT Std}[
     Numbers=OldStyle,
     Ligatures=Common,
     ItalicFeatures={
          SmallCapsFeatures = {FakeSlant=0.2}}]
```

Any suggestions?

Edit:
The font Sabon LT Std has small caps in the roman but not in the italics, nor any of the others.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Sabon LT Std}[
    UprightFont = *-roman,
    BoldFont = *-bold,
    ItalicFont = *-italic,
    BoldItalicFont = *-bolditalic,
    Numbers=OldStyle,
    Ligatures=Common]   
\begin{document}
\textsc{Small caps}
\textit{Italics}
\textit{\textsc{Italic small caps}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try declaring a `SmallCapsFont`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Would you mind adding a  [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) (i.e code starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`): this will make it easier for us to help you!

Comment: Yep, added to original.

Comment: Please don't use `minimal` for examples. It is not suitable.

Comment: Somewhat off-topic: Any chance you could switch from `Sabon LT` to `Sabon Next LT`? The latter font features an italics/small-caps font shape combination...

Comment: @Mico I need to keep it with Sabon because this is meant to stay within the type identity of an original document, which is in Sabon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have your font, but this here works fine for me

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
    ItalicFeatures =
    {
     SmallCapsFont={Arial},
     SmallCapsFeatures={FakeSlant=-0.2,RawFeature={+smcp}}
    },
     BoldItalicFeatures={
     SmallCapsFont={Arial/B},
     SmallCapsFeatures={FakeSlant=-0.2,RawFeature={+smcp}}
    }
    ]{TeX Gyre Termes}
\begin{document}
normal
\textsc{Small caps}
\textit{Italics}
\textit{\textsc{Italic small caps}}

\textit{\textsc{Italic \bfseries small caps}}

\textbf{\textit{Some \textsc{Italic small caps}}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This has the same problem: there is no italic small caps. It all renders as the regular case version of the font.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that this was your main problem. You can add the smcp-feature, see my edit.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Just curious to know, is there any options available in `LaTeX-dvips-PS2PDF` to get manual italics?